# how to convert an array to a string format

Tags: php, arrays, string, arraylist

i have an array in the format

> array() {["2011-07-29"]=>  39 ["2011-07-30"]=>  39  ["2011-07-31"]=>  39 ["2011-08-01"]=>  40}

i need to convert it to a string format like this (the below is a var_dump result)

> string(584) "[new Date(2011,07,29),39], [new Date(2011, 07, 30),39],[new Date(2011, 07, 31),39], [new Date(2011, 08, 01),40]"

had anyone faced it before , iam stuck with this now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $a = Array("2011-07-29" => 39, "2011-07-30"=> 39, "2011-07-31"=> 39, "2011-08-01"=> 40);
    $sa = array();
    foreach($a as $k => $v){
        $sa[] = "[new Date(".preg_replace('/-/',', ',$k)."),$v]";
    }
    $s = implode(', ',$sa);
    var_dump( $s );
?>
```

Edit: Improved to match better features of @Alvaro's answer (virtually identical - and answered first), but with simpler string building (I find sprintf an unnecessary layer of abstraction)

```
<?php
    $input = array(
        '2011-07-29' => 39,
        '2011-07-30' => 39,
        '2011-07-31' => 39,
        '2011-08-01' => 40,
    );
    $aux = array();
    foreach($input as $date => $number){
        $aux[] = "[new Date(" . str_replace('-',', ',$date) . "),$number]";
    }
    $output = implode(', ', $aux);
    var_dump($input, $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to loop on the array and parse each date using `parse_date`. Once you have the dates in a usable format, you can build your new string.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not direct way. Try using a `json_encode()` on your array and massage the output.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
<?php

$input = array(
    '2011-07-29' => 39,
    '2011-07-30' => 39,
    '2011-07-31' => 39,
    '2011-08-01' => 40,
);

$aux = array();

foreach($input as $date => $number){
    $aux[] = sprintf('[new Date(%s),%d]', str_replace('-', ',', $date), $number);
}

$output = implode(', ', $aux);

var_dump($input, $output);
```